# Set up UITabBar without UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uitabbar

After finally getting my UITabBarConntroller to work, I have read in the apple docs, that I should not use a UITabBarController as a child of my Navigation Controller.

My app, segues from a TVC to my TabBar, which has a few tabs.

For example

[image]

I want to modal segue from each coloured view.

I am wondering if the red view should be the delegate for each of the views, or should they all be independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do here is basically to implement your own Tabbarcontroller. Apple does not recommend to put a Tabbarcontroller as a child of a Navigationcontroller due to usability reasons. Technically, you *can* do this **but** it is not really good as users of iOS are used to have a TabbarController as the root view of each navigation stack and therefore an approach like yours might make your app confusing and hard to understand.

Nevertheless, if you insist to stick to your idea, you can just simply put a tab bar controller into a navigation controller in your storyboard which should do its work. Still, I would recommend to rethink your app's navigation structure. Take a look at other popular Apple apps and Apple's [Tabbar Controller Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/TabBarControllers.html) as inspiration.

Comment: Yeah, trying to figure out a better way to restructure. The tableview has a list of people, which segues to the view - each tab will have different info, ie business card view, personal details, meeting history etc. The tab structure seems to make sense for this.

Comment: come to think of it, I'll just have a tabbar on the first view, and the modally presents to the next. You have to then dismiss that modal view to get back  to the view that has all the options. KISS approach.

Comment: maybe just make on detail view controller which has a tableview and a segmented controller. With each click on the segmented control you could reload the table view and present the persons appropriate data.

Comment: each view is very different from the last, one is a TVC other is a plain VC. So wouldnt work, thanks for idea though.